# subl does not open in command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, macos, unix

I am unable to open sublime text from the command line in my mac os.
Here is what I did so far

```
    echo $PATH
```

My path says  /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/sr027976/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin:/Users/sr027976/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/bin:/Users/sr027976/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin:/Users/sr027976/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

```
ln \-s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl

source ~/.bash_profile

subl .
```

subl . says command not found.

I am unsure what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Does `open -a "Sublime Text 2"` opens Sublime Text ? If so, can't you just make an alias `alias subl='open -a "Sublime Text 2"'` ?

(Don't know if aliases works the same on MacOSX)